# Using the two partial differential equations construct a partial differential equation containing only variable 'G' and solve it.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, soliton-theory

The two equations are:
$$a\frac{\partial R}{\partial x} + bR = cG \rightarrow (1)$$
$$d\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x^2} + eG = f\frac{\partial R}{\partial t} \rightarrow (2)$$
where a,b,c,d,e and f are constants. 'R' and 'G' are functions of independent variables 'x' and 't'.

Using equations (1) and (2) construct a partial differential equation containing only variable 'G'. If possible also give the solution for the same equation.

Can the constructed partial differential equation in terms of 'G' be modified to get the Korteweg-de Vries equation ?

This is the wikipedia link for Korteweg-de Vries equation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation

Comment: I'm not sure why the Korteweg-de Vries equation is relevant. It's a single partial differential equation of one function, while this is two partial differential equations of two functions.

Comment: The Korteweg-de Vries equation is a partial differential equation of one function with two independent variables. What I know is whether the constructed equation which should have only one function 'G' in terms of two independent variables 'x' and 't' can be modified to get the same form as Korteweg-de Vries equation ?

Comment: But it's not the only such equation. There are plenty of other partial differential equations of one function in two variables. As far as I can tell, it has nothing to do with this system of equations.

Comment: It doesn't have to have the same form as the KdV equation. I am just asking whether it will or not ?